# Torrent Program for Debian with webUI

Tags: bittorrent

Does torrent software exist which allows access through a WebUI? Useful features which I'd really like include:

- Timers
- Allows downloading of files over HTTP/FTP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transmission ?

https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/WebInterface

Comment: Are there any guides on how to set this up on a headless server?

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [rtorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/) with [rtgui](http://code.google.com/p/rtgui/) as its web front end.  Very easy to use and setup.

Both are built in to the Ubuntu universe.

```
sudo apt-get install rtorrent rtgui
```

Also in the repo is *rtpg-www*, but I haven't used it.

Comment: +1. peronslly i use the wtorrent front end, but its all good. - the onyl slight downside of rtorrent is theres no queueing (everything comes down when you add it) - other than that its ace., can even add things over ssh / screen

Comment: @Sirex - Here's a script to queue downloads. http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=8992 Also rtorrent has some pretty extensive rules you can apply to help with seeding and overal scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/).

It has a built in [webui](http://www.doknowevil.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/deluge-webui.png). One that is just as powerful as the GUI with all the same features.

Even better it also works in thin client mode that allows you to use the native GTK desktop GUI on a Linux/Windows/Mac system but connect it to another systems daemon backend (turn on classic mode in the options). Once setup it's completely seamless and just as functional as if it was running locally. This lets torrents/magnet links work just if you where using BitTorrent on your desktop (although personally I just save them to a shared folder that I set Deluge up to look for new torrents in periodically which is another handy feature).

[Instructions](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient) for both webui and thin client.

It does have a scheduler, although I'm not sure how good it is. But another advantage is that it has a cli interface, this allows you to write shell scripts to control it with little work.

For example a simple script to stop seeding. Just put it in a cron job at whatever time you want.

```
SEEDING=`deluge-console "info" | grep "State:\ Seeding" -B 1 | grep "ID" | cut -f2 -d\ `
echo $SEEDING | while read ID; do
    echo "Pausing: $ID";
    #deluge-console  "pause $ID"
done
```

It's a full BitTorrent client. It has a lot more features than something like Transmission. It's somewhat like Azurus (Vuze) was back in the day (except without bloat).

Another control idea if you own a smartphone is to look at something like [Transdroid](http://www.transdroid.org/). It supports Deluge and quite a few other programs (personally I couldn't get Deluge to work but I think I had a odd setup).

Answer (score 0):

[MLDonkey](http://mldonkey.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) supports a number of peer-to-peer protocols, including BitTorrent. It has a [Web interface](http://mldonkey.sourceforge.net/WebUI), as well as a [Telnet-based one](http://mldonkey.sourceforge.net/TelnetUI) and one suitable for [desktop clients](http://mldonkey.sourceforge.net/Gui).

Answer (score 0):

Transmission is your best bet. It can run in headless mode accessed via a slick browser interface, but also has a decent local GUI if you want to go that way. Configuration is simple yet powerful, and the browser UI has just enough functionality to make it useful without bloat.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has mentioned [Vuze](http://www.vuze.com)? It is not open source but it has its own web based interface (remote.vuze.com) and a very nice plugin (which I prefer) called HTML Web UI.